# Error Cannot use multi-field values as a filter value. Tengo problemas con el manejo del ORM en django en la fusión de dos o más tablas

Tags: django, django-models, orm, django-views

Al momento de querer fusionar dos tablas que están relacionadas y buscar objetos tengo el problema en que no me funciona como debe de ser, el error que me marca es este:

File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 1064, in resolve_lookup_value
self, reuse=can_reuse, allow_joins=allow_joins,
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 1343, in resolve_expression
raise TypeError('Cannot use multi-field values as a filter value.')
TypeError: Cannot use multi-field values as a filter value.

```
orderItem = OrderItem.objects.order_by('-date_added').values('order__customer', 'order__transaction_id', 'product__name', 'quantity', 'order__date_orderd').filter(order=order)
```

no me deja realizar el .filter(order=order)

el código que estoy generando es este:

Este es el código en el archivo de views.py:

```
@method_decorator(login_required, name='dispatch')
class ProfileUpdate(UpdateView, DetailView):
    form_class = ProfileForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('profile')
    template_name = 'registration/profile_form.html'
    model = Order, OrderItem, Customer, Product

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(ProfileUpdate, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)      
        data = cartData(self.request)
        cartItems = data['cartItems']
        customer = Customer.objects.all().values('user')
        customer = self.request.user.customer
        product = Product.objects.all().values('name')
        order = Order.objects.order_by('-date_orderd').filter(complete=True, customer=customer).select_related('customer').values('transaction_id', 'date_orderd')
        orderItem = OrderItem.objects.order_by('-date_added').values('order__customer', 'order__transaction_id', 'product__name', 'quantity', 'order__date_orderd').filter(order=order)
        print(orderItem)
        context['cartItems'] = cartItems
        context['customer'] = customer
        context['order'] = order
        context['orderItem'] = orderItem
        return context 


    def get_object(self):
        # recuperar el objeto que se va editar
        profile, created = Profile.objects.get_or_create(user=self.request.user)
        return profile
```

En el archivo de los modelos en los que estoy relacionando son: models.py

from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

```
class Customer(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True, verbose_name="Usuario")
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True, verbose_name="Nombre de Cliente")
    email = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s %s' % (self.id, self.user)


class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, verbose_name="Nombre de Producto")
    category = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, verbose_name="Categoría o Tipo de Producto")
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=7, decimal_places=2, verbose_name="Precio")
    digital = models.BooleanField(default=False, null=True, blank=False, verbose_name="Producto Digital")
    description = models.TextField(blank=True, verbose_name="Descripción")
    photo_main = models.ImageField(upload_to='photos/products/%Y/%m/%d/', verbose_name="Imagen Principal")
    is_published = models.BooleanField(default=True, verbose_name="Publicar Producto")
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, verbose_name="Fecha de creación")
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, verbose_name="Fecha de edición")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Order(models.Model):
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True, verbose_name="Cliente")
    date_orderd = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, verbose_name="Fecha de pedido")
    complete = models.BooleanField(default=False, null=True, blank=False, verbose_name="Compra Completa")
    transaction_id = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, verbose_name="Identificación de transacción")
    
    def __str__(self):
       return str(self.transaction_id)

class OrderItem(models.Model):
     product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True, verbose_name="Producto")
     order = models.ForeignKey(Order, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True, verbose_name="Pedido")
     quantity = models.IntegerField(default=0, null=True, blank=True, verbose_name="Cantidad de producto")
     date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, verbose_name="Fecha de agregado")
```

En el archivo HTML esto es lo que quiero regresar de datos (la mera verdad no sé si esté bien el como lo estoy regresando):

```
 <section id="dashboard" class="py-4">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
          <h2 class="text-center">Bienvenido {{user.first_name}}</h2>
           {% if orderItems %}
          <p>Estos son las compras que has realizado</p>
            <table class="table" id="ttabla">
              <thead class="thead-light" id="tttabla">
                <tr>
                  <th>Cod Pedido</th>
                  <th>#</th>
                  <th>Producto</th>
                  <th>Fecha </th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                {% for orderItem in orderItems %}
                  <tr id="tttabla">
                  <td>{{orderItem.order.transaction_id}}</td>
                  <td>{{orderItem.quantity}}</td>
                  <td>{{orderItem.product}}</td>
                  <td>{{orderItem.order.date_orderd}}</td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
                {% endfor %}
            </table>
                {% else %}
            <br />
            <p class="text-center">No has realizado ninguna compra</p>
                {% endif %}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
```

Answer (score 0):

La solución la encontré haciendo esto en views.py:

```
@method_decorator(login_required, name='dispatch')
class ProfileUpdate(UpdateView, DetailView):
    form_class = ProfileForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('profile')
    template_name = 'registration/profile_form.html'
    model = Order, OrderItem, Customer, Product

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(ProfileUpdate, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)      
        data = cartData(self.request)
        cartItems = data['cartItems']
        customer = Customer.objects.all().values('user')
        customer = self.request.user.customer
        product = Product.objects.all().values('name')
        order = Order.objects.order_by('-date_orderd').filter(complete=True, customer=customer).select_related('customer').values('transaction_id', 'date_orderd')
        order_ids = Order.objects.order_by('-date_orderd').values_list('id', flat=True).filter(complete=True, customer=customer)
        orderItems = OrderItem.objects.order_by('-date_added').values('order__customer', 'order__transaction_id', 'product__name', 'quantity', 'order__date_orderd').filter(order__in=order_ids).distinct()
        print(orderItems)
        context['cartItems'] = cartItems
        context['customer'] = customer
        context['order'] = order
        context['orderItem'] = orderItems
        return context 


    def get_object(self):
        # recuperar el objeto que se va editar
        profile, created = Profile.objects.get_or_create(user=self.request.user)
        return profile
```

Ya solo me falta como llamarlo en la parte de HTML, ¿Alguien podría apoyarme con eso?